# Get the content of a caption when referencing a figure

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I have a pretty special requirement for my current thesis. When I reference a figure from my appendix in the main document I have to cite the content of the caption as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % dummy image
\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy text
\usepackage{cleveref}   % can be used if necessary

\begin{document}
    \section{Image}
        \blindduck

        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            \caption{Duck image}
            \label{fig:duck}
        \end{figure}

    \section{Reference}
        See \Cref{fig:duck} for more information.

        %Desired output Figure 1 "Duck image"
\end{document}
```

When I reference my image I would like to cite the content from the figure's caption as well, like "See Figure 1.2 "Duck image". Is it possible to get the content of a caption by label and when, how can I reach the content from a specific caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand\captionref[1]{\Cref{#1}:~\nameref{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\hfil\fbox{This is the nice figure}
\caption{This is the caption of the nice figure.\label{xxx}}
\end{figure}
This is the boring text, so stop reading this  
and please see again the \captionref{xxx}.  
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine. I didn't know of the package `nameref` so far. Is it required to load `nameref` to load before `hyperref`?

Comment: @faltfe In general, you have to be careful with the order  of  packages for cross references and `hyperref` matter,  but at least in this example the problem is not `nameref`  but `cleveref`.  If you load it before of `hyperref`, the link of of the number  is lost.